# I can't understand this solution with $\equiv$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, real-numbers, perfect-powers

I found a solution for finding the units digit of a sum. It said that the $\equiv$ means  "has the same units digit as". Using this, they said that $3^1+3^3+3^5+...+3^{2009} \equiv 3+7+3+...+3+7+3$ But they said that this is $\equiv$ to $0+0+0+...+3$. How did they come up with this?

Comment: Please write a more-informative title.  Your question has nearly nothing to do with the $\equiv$ sign.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look up modular arithmetic.

Comment: @Community : "As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking" : no it isn't.

Comment: Surprised that anyone would downvote your question.  You have shown work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You correctly identified that $\pmod{10}$, the sequence is equivalent to

$$3 + 7 + 3 + 7 + 3 + 7 + 3 + 7 + \cdots.$$

You then asked how it could be concluded that the final sum is equivalent to $3 \pmod{10}.$

$(2009 - 1)$ is equivalent to $(0) \pmod{4}$, rather than $(2) \pmod{4}$.  Therefore, there is an **odd** number of terms in the sequence, rather than an even number of terms.

**If** there were an even number of terms, the sum of the sequence could be viewed as

$$\left[ ~(3 + 7) + (3 + 7) + \cdots + (3 + 7) ~\right] \pmod{10}.$$

Since the sum $\pmod{10}$ of each pair of terms is $0$, the overall sum of the sequence **would** be $(0)$, **if** there were an even number of terms.

However, there is an odd number of terms.  Therefore, the sequence should be viewed as

$$\left\{ ~\left[ ~(3 + 7) + (3 + 7) + \cdots + (3 + 7) ~\right] + 3 ~\right\} \pmod{10}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! "$2009-1$ is equivalent to $(0)(mod 4)$. Therefore, there is an odd number of terms in the sequence..." This can actually help me get to the last step of the problem right away.